# action struts with file in response not working with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, struts

i have a struts action that's have a doc as response this is the code :

```
public class GenerateBlame extends Action
{ 



    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("it's ok!");
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\free\\Desktop\\myworkspace\\gestionRH\\WebRoot\\fiches\\decisionRetraitSanction.doc"));
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
        Range r = doc.getRange();
        r.replaceText("<dateDemande>", "test");

        doc.write(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\free\\Desktop\\myworkspace\\gestionRH\\WebRoot\\fiches\\decision.doc"));
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/rtf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=Decision");
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\free\\Desktop\\myworkspace\\gestionRH\\WebRoot\\fiches\\decision.doc");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;
    /*  while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();*/
        return null;
    }
}
```

i want to call this action via ajax id do like this :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../generateBlame.do",
 });
```

i can't get the file downloeded as i'did whith a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like [this jQuery download plugin](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx) or equivalent.

Comment: i imported the js file of this plugin from this site https://raw.github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js and then $.fileDownload('mypath'); firebug shows me this error : TypeError: $.fileDownload is not a function

Comment: @fatiDev If you have a new question, ask a new question; don't wrap it up in an existing one, or in comments to an answer.

Comment: the new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267632/jquery-file-donwloed-plugin