# jQuery file download plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, download

I imported the js file of this plugin from [this site](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js) as follows 
`<script type="text/javascript"  src="/gestionRH/js/jquery/jqueryFileDownload.js"></script>` and then

```
$.fileDownload('mypath');
```

Firebug shows me this error: `TypeError: $.fileDownload is not a function`

chrome shows this : Uncaught `TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new d.fn.init(a,b,g)} has no method 'fileDownload'`

this the whole code

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>


    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>

     <script type="text/javascript"  src="/gestionRH/js/jquery/jquery13_min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" id="download" value="download">

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#download").live("click",function(){
     $.fileDownload('C:\\Users\\free\\Desktop\\myworkspace\\gestionRH\\WebRoot\\fiches\\note.doc');
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: **Never** directly link to GitHub files; it's _not_ a CDN. Either host the file yourself, upload it to a CDN of your own or find it on an existing CDN.

Comment: Are you using any kind of noconflict() ?

Comment: Are you loading it? Anything in the JS console?

Comment: Are you including the file on the page you are using it on? You need to do something like this:

`<script src="path/to/jquery.fileDownload.js"></script>`

Comment: @fatiDev, you said you are including the file? Is it successful? Do you notice the file actually loading on the "Net" tab of Firebug?

Comment: in the the official site if the plugin http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx ; the say that's it works with firefox11 and i have firefox14 can this be the origin of the problem

Comment: I doubt that it would be the problem. Have you tried it in other browsers?

Comment: @fatiDev Please respond to the above comments, don't ignore them.

Comment: chrome but still have newer version 21 and the say just 17

Comment: @JamWaffles i'm using a local file where i copied the plugin code

Comment: @ there is a lot a version of jquery in my project , but i deal with that whith jquery.noconflict() method

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah in the firebug console , i see the file is loaded

Comment: @mikez302 yeah that's what i do , look my question edited

Comment: hope i responded to all of you , it was not intentionally , but there was lot of comments and i was lost , thank you all

Comment: i posted the error displayed by chrome console on the question

Comment: i installed firefox 11 and the problem still remains

Comment: @fatiDev, you said you copied the plugin code into a local file. Are you including this file after jQuery? If you put it before, it may not work.

Comment: @mikez302 yeah it's after jquery , i'm using jquery 1.5

Comment: i tried 1.3 also , the same problem !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for those who will face the same problem the problem is due to this : the path was not correct i have to download from a server so the path is

```
 $.fileDownload('http://localhost:8080/path/to/file');
```

not `$.fileDownload('C:\\Users\path\to\file');`